# Grok pattern for optional fields

Tags: logstash-grok

I'm trying to get some sort of grok pattern to work with the following logging format :

```
2017-02-21 23:45:41.7734 | MyLogger | INFO | PathInfo [/json/api/GetData] Duration [821,1381 ms] IpAddress [xx.xx.xx.xx] RequestParam [{"MyObj":{"UserId":87026,"SessionId":1022977,}]
```

Where RequestParam is an optional field, but i'm a grok newbie so i can't find the working pattern for this line of log

Answer (score 1):

try to make your custom pattern using this tool :

[grok discover pattern](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/discover?#)

maybe it can help you:

```
%{DATESTAMP} \| %{WORD:Loggername} \| %{LOGLEVEL} \| PathInfo \[%{PATH}\] Duration \[%{DATA}\] IpAddress%{CISCO_REASON} %{SYSLOG5424SD:IP} RequestParam %{SYSLOG5424SD:RequestParam}
```

Comment: Thx for response. I tried this pattern : %{DATESTAMP} \| %{WORD:Loggername} \| %{WORD:LOGLEVEL} \| PathInfo \[%{PATH:Method}\] Duration \[%{DATA:Duration}\] IpAddress%{CISCO_REASON} %{SYSLOG5424SD:IP} RequestParam %{SYSLOG5424SD:RequestParam}